# Kendo Grid Selection with checkboxes

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc, kendo-ui

Im want to have such an easy selection like telerik has in the radgrid like this:
http://demos.telerik.com/aspnet-ajax/grid/examples/functionality/selecting/row-selection/defaultcs.aspx

Anyone has an Idea how to add such a selection functionality to the Kendo Grid?

(I know that's the same Company ;))

Thanks!!

Answer (score 0):

Please try this below url's you can get some ideas about your requirment

http://demos.kendoui.com/web/grid/selection.html

http://demos.telerik.com/aspnet-mvc/razor/grid/clientsideevents?theme=vista

Comment: thanks, i known this urls already... i want to have a checkbox column in the Kendo grid to select multiple entries as easy as possible...

Answer (score 0):

From this url you can get one sample zip file related to your requirment . Pls download it and check

http://www.kendoui.com/code-library/mvc/grid/checkbox-column-and-incell-editing.aspx